# why I can't use path draw a line,but I use drawline method it's ok?

Tags: android, canvas, path

I use `canvas.drawPath` can't draw a line,why? but if use the `canvas.drawLine()` method,it's ok,this is my code.

```
public class TestView extends View {
public TestView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public TestView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public TestView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

    //canvas.drawLine(0,0,100,100,p);

    Path path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(0,0);
    path.lineTo(100,100);
    canvas.drawPath(path,p);
}
```

}

who can tell me why? thanks advanced

Comment: Have you tried adding `p.setStrokeWidth(5);` and  `p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);` to the Paint object?

Comment: yes,you are right , it need the `style`